# Download ggvis plot from reactive set

Tags: r, download, shiny, png, ggvis

I have a shiny app that allows a user to choose what to plot on the x and y axis based on a loaded data frame.  I am trying to allow the user to download the current plot view.  I am opening launching the app in Google Chrome because I know it does not work to save a file if the app is launched within R studio.  As of now it saves a png file, but it is blank.

[Screenshot of app UI can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBuJN.png)

I have used these posts to try to resolve the issue:

[Downloading png from Shiny (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764481/downloading-png-from-shiny-r)

[Downloading png from Shiny (R) pt. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008434/downloading-png-from-shiny-r-pt-2)

The app does not work if `vis()` is changed to a function rather than a reactive.  However, when `filteredData()` is changed from a reactive to a function, the app still works the same.  However, a blank png is still yield if within `downloadHandler(...` I have `vis()`, `filteredData()` or `print(filteredData())`.  If `print(vis())` is used, another window pops up in the browser that says "Key / already in use".  A minimal working code that replicates the issue is below and any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

```
#Check packages to use in library
library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used
library('stringr') #string opperator
library('ggvis') #allows for interactive ploting
library('dplyr')

alldata <- iris

#establish options for drop down menus
specieschoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Species))
petalwchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Petal.Width))
petallchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Petal.Length))
sepallchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Sepal.Length))
sepalwchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Sepal.Width))

# UI

ui<-fluidPage(
titlePanel("Explorer"),
fluidRow(
column(4,
       wellPanel(
         h4("Apply Filters"),
         selectInput(inputId = "species", label="Select a Species:", choices = sort(specieschoices), selected="setosa", multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE),
         selectInput(inputId = "petalw", label="Select Petal Width:", choices = sort(petalwchoices), selected=petalwchoices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE),
         selectInput(inputId = "petall", label="Select Petal Length", choices = sort(petallchoices), selected=petallchoices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE),
         selectInput(inputId = "sepall", label="Select Sepal Length", choices = sort(sepallchoices), selected=sepallchoices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE),
         selectInput(inputId = "sepalw", label="Select Sepal Width", choices = sort(sepalwchoices), selected=sepalwchoices, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE),
         downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download Plot')
         )),
column(8,
       ggvisOutput("plot1")
),
column(4,
       wellPanel(
         h4("Data Variables"),
         selectInput(inputId = "x", label="Select x-axis Variable:", choices=as.character(names(alldata[,1:4])),selected='Petal.Length', multiple = FALSE),
         selectInput(inputId = "y", label="Select y-axis Variable:", choices=as.character(names(alldata[,1:4])),selected='Petal.Width', multiple = FALSE)
       ))
))

#SERVER
server<-function(input,output,session)
{

#Set up reactive variables
filteredData <- reactive({

# Apply filters
m <- alldata %>% filter(
  `Species` %in% input$species,
  `Petal.Width` %in% input$petalw,
  `Petal.Length` %in% input$petall,
  `Sepal.Width` %in% input$sepalw,
  `Sepal.Length` %in% input$sepall
)
m <- droplevels(as.data.frame(m))
m
})

vis <- reactive({

xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$x))
yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$y))

p1 = filteredData() %>%
  ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
  layer_points(size.hover := 200,
               fillOpacity:= 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 1,
               fill = ~Species
  )

})

#Actually plots the data
vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")

################# THIS IS THE PART THAT I NEED HELP WITH#####################
output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
  filename = paste0(input$y, '_vs_', input$x, "_", Sys.Date(), ".png"),
  content = function(file) {
    png(file)
    vis()
    dev.off()
  },
  contentType = 'image/png'
)
##############################################################################
}

#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating another function that created a ggplot plot that was an exact replicate of my ggvis plot to use with the downloadHandler.